# javascript not working after server reboot

Tags: php, javascript, html, apache

Earlier today I had an issue with my server and it crashed so I had to reboot. Since I rebooted it I've been seeing some strange behavior in some of my php pages. Particularly, some javascript stuff doesn't seem to be working at all. (There are some other issues, but I feel like they're stemming from the failing javascript.)

I'm still getting used to web programming and using servers, so I have no idea why this javascript wouldn't be working after the reboot. I can post the script here if need be - I don't know if this is just a generic thing or is going to be specific to my script.

For the record it's an Apache server on a Redhat machine.

Comment: Look at your browser's console (F12).

Comment: It failed on `[18:30:45.307] GET http://wks-l0000120674/nephiere/validation.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 47ms]`

I don't know why that would've worked before, there was never a `validation.js` in this folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript is executed in the client browser not in the server, so as long as you did not make any modifications to the javascript files, there should not be anything wrong caused by the server.

Did you try accessing your website using another computer ?

Comment: Alright, I did just access it from another machine and it worked. Strange, I haven't rebooted the other machine at all, or changed anything with firefox. I wonder what happened. I'll try rebooting and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it appears that the page is loading a javascript library from a network location which it cannot find (`http://wks-l0000120674/nephiere/validation.js`). Thus it will load if the client machine (not the server) is connected to the network AND the wks-l0000120674 workstation is up and on the network AND the client machine has rights to request files from wks-l0000120674. On the reboot you may have booted wks-l0000120674 off the network (assuming that wks-l0000120674 is part of the same network as the server and the server also provides DHCP services). Make sure you can still get to this location from the *client machine*.

Comment: wks-l0000120674 is the server. I'm assuming it's up and on the network as I am able to access it from my station.